# PHP fileupload not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, file-upload

I'm having troubles uploading large files. I've set required settings in my ini files /apache2/php.ini and /cli/php.ini, and in .htaccess. I can upload small files like 38KB but unable to upload larger files. I want to be able to upload upto 1MB

```
    $target_path = "/var/www/html/uploads/";
    $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
        die("The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded");
    } 
    else{
        die ("There was an error uploading the file, please try again!");
    }
```

My .htaccess file

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 90M
php_value post_max_size 100M
php_value memory_limit 128M
php_value max_execution_time 10000
```

Other settings in ini file

```
max_input_time = -1 //apparently this is unlimited?
```

Thanks

Comment: Check with phpinfo() if your htaccess values were accepted.

Comment: Yes they are. The changes are reflected in my ini file

Comment: And what error do yo actually get? What does the error logfile say?

Comment: check `$_FILES['uploadedfile']['error']` for file upload error

Comment: @SimoneNigro I did echoed $_FILES['uploadedfile']['error'] in the else part of the if statement and got "2".

Comment: Value: 2; The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form. http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: Ohhhh shoot! Forgot that part. Thanks man!

Answer (score -1):

Hi Just additional info,

You need to check if the php.ini you are changing is the active one.
for example if you use lampp/xampp you should take a look at the installation folder example:

- in linux it ussually reside in /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini
- linux manual /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

you can try a search the ini files in your system by searching for it or using phpinfo()

Comment: I am using the right one, which phpinfo() pointed to "Loaded Configuration File": /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini. Also I can see the changes I make in htaccess file in phpinfo()